# Ionic 4/5 - Prevent iOS Keyboard from pushing content up

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been working on a classic Angular App wrapped with Ionic but have some issues once I build my app.

On one of my screens I have a sticky searchbar and each time I click on it triggers the Keyboard sadly the keyboard pushed everything up so far I've tried to play with Ionic Keyboard Plugin and it's disableScroll function but nothing, the App still scrolls up when the keyboard pops-up..

My code:

bonus-searchbar.component.html

```
<div class="sticky-searchbar" *ngIf="isSticky" [@enterAnimation] [ngClass]="{'tag-radius': isTag}">
  <mat-form-field class="search-input" appearance="none" hideRequiredMarker>
    <img class="search-icon" [src]="isMobile ? 'assets/icons/search.svg ': 'assets/icons/white_search.svg'">
    <input (keyup.enter)="bonusSearch(search)" (keyup)="searchBonus()" placeholder="Rechercher" class="searchbar-input"
      [(ngModel)]="search" name="searchbar" required matInput type="text" #searchBar (focus)="toto()">
    <div class="focus-border"></div>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

bonus-searchbar.component.ts

```
  toto() {
    this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillShow()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('keyboard will shown');
      console.log(this.keyboard.isVisible);
      this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    });
  }
```

My first console log gets triggered,
 The second one always return false even when the virtual keyboard is displayed and finally when my disableScroll() gets called it works and disables scrolling, but it doesn't disable the initial push of content created by the Keyboard..

Any ideas?